# How to output everything contained in MySQL connection?

Tags: php, html, mysql, database

So far, I have

```
<?php

$con = mysql_connect("...", "...", "...")
or die(mysql_eror);
```

but how can I output (to PHP/HTML) everything contained in that MySQL??

Comment: please read php code. and if you want start , star by mysqli or pdo

Comment: You execute a SQL select statement, loop through the result set and echo it to the page; exactly as shown in the PHP MySQL documents.... except that (as your obviously just learning) use MySQLi or PDO instead, as MySQL is scheduled to die real soon now

Comment: please, go to php.net and read some manuals before asking questions like this!

Comment: Please use mysqli_ or PDO instead of mysql_ extension.

Comment: RTLM? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Select_%28SQL%29

Answer (score 2):

If you mean `$con` object, you may just write:

```
print_r($con);
```

or

```
var_dump($con);
```

or with `<pre>` for better readability in browser:

```
echo "<pre>";  // <pre> is HTML tag that will preserve line breaks in output
var_dump($con);
echo "</pre>";
```

or

```
echo "<pre>";
print_r($con);
echo "</pre>";
```

These functions will print all properties (variables) inside that object (including arrays with their structure). However that kind of object contains functions (methods in objective programming nomenclature), and they cannot be printed.

To list methods inside object of `mysql` type you have to see documentation.

And one more very important thing - please read red box [here (link)](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-db-query.php) and use mysqli_ or PDO instead of mysql_.

Comment: it says "Resource id #3" (or "resource(3) of type (mysql link)" if using var_dump($con)), what does that mean?

Comment: Correct, it will say that because $con /is/ a resource, a database connection, nothing more and nothing less

Comment: but how do i output content of that database?

Comment: @mrgerbik2013 your knowledge about databases is not enough to understand many things required to accomplish that what you want to do. Thats why your question was downvoted. Mysql object in PHP is just a set of functions to retrieve data from database. It does not contain any data from database. You should see some video tutorials about PHP and MySQL fundamentals, maybe http://phpacademy.org or http://thenewboston.org